# Excel: Trimming trailing and leading spaces on its own place

Tags: excel, excel-formula, trim

I have a column with around 100 values that I want to trim. I know that `Trim()` does the job, but the problem is that I'll need to create a separate column, write that formula so that has it has the Trimmed version of the existing column.

Is there a way to trim the existing column so that it changes the values on its on place?

Perhaps any command in the Data tab, that I can simply select all cells that I want to trim and with a simple click without needing to create other columns?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with a VBA macro